# Figuring out number of threads the java application should use when running on kubernetes with resources and limits

Tags: java, multithreading, kubernetes, cpu, throttling

We have a java application running on EKS as a container in the pod spawning 40 threads and K8s resources set as

```
requests:
  cpu: "1"
  memory: 1Gi
limits:
  cpu: "2"
  memory: 2Gi
```

Each thread(say parent-thread) basically reads a file typically of 50MB size from S3, loops thru the records in the file, processes each record, creates a batch of 5MB and spawns another thread(say child-thread) that posts the payload(batch) thru async rest api call to another system that ingests the payload.

Based on the observations, it takes close to 6-7 secs for one batch to be processed and posted. And the whole s3 file is being processed in ~65-70 secs. This should also be the time the parent-thread is active for.

Based on my understanding of K8s requests and limits, since we have a cpu limit of 2 cores or 2000 millicores, when equated to cpu_period of 100ms cycles, the application uses 2 cores every second. Since limits are enforced on the whole container, all 40 threads would be sharing this 200 ms, or to say each thread runs for only 5 ms and gets throttled. **Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here**

To avoid cpu throttling

1. should we have our application run only 2 threads?
2. OR since, each thread is running for a total of 60-70 secs, should the application run same number of threads as cores?
3. We couldn't figure out why we have set 2 core limit per container, but given that the whole EKS cluster majorly runs only our application(as a container within a pod in a node, there are other sidecar containers too), is there an advantage to have say 8 pods running each with `limit=2 cores` on a 16 vCPU node than running 2 pods running each with `limit=8 cores` ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your application is getting throttled?  As you've described the problem, you have one serial thread doing work, and several other threads that are only doing HTTP calls.  The other threads are I/O bound; they're sitting idle waiting for the HTTP response to return.  I'd approximately expect your application to have the one busy thread and using more or less 1.0 aggregate CPU, which is less than the configured limits.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes. Sorry for not being clear. I have set my application with 40 parent threads. So, they all trying to run in parallel which spawn child-threads that do async http

Comment: I think we are on the wrong path here. 1 or 2 Gi are not much for a Java application. While they will *use* much less once they started up, they `alloc` a metric pooload of it and the JVM will not return once allocated memory to the OS. Take a JBOSS - it will request in excess of 4 Gi from the OS, while internally reporting that only a couple of 100Mi are used.